# Is there a better way to say that a historic record "goes back to [some time in the past]"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have a record of transactions that "goes back to 2011", but is there a better way to say that? I'm considering "a record that extends back to 2011", but I find both phrases a bit too colloquial.

Comment: Neither is "too colloquial" for my taste, unless perhaps you're applying for a job as manservant to the Queen of England.

Comment: Continuing states and regularly repeated events are often said to _date from_ some time in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use **date from** or **date back**

> **date from**: to have existed since a particular time in the past

These masterly cantatas date from different periods in Bach's life.

> **date back**: to have existed for a particular length of time or since a particular time:

This tradition **dates back to** medieval times.

Please check [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/date-back)

Answer (score 1):

I am in agreement with @Robusto that "goes back to" is fine for everyday usage.

However, if more formality is required, how about:

- "[Commencing](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/commence) on"

This reverses the direction of time to a forward direction (as opposed to "going back to"), and gives a sense of ongoing continuity of records, although you will likely need to be more exact about the starting date of your transactions - *"commencing 2011"* is likely to arouse suspicion - a month, and ideally an exact date would be preferable.

- "[Originating](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/originate)"

However, arguably this does not convey the *continuity* of records - IMO, *originating* would be more applicable to a single, specific document.